# vsftpd returns 0,0,0,0 in response to PASV

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, vsftpd

I set up an FTP server on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu16.04) with passive mode (`PASV`), but it doesn't work. However, it works with `EPSV`, don't know why. I searched around but find no answers, any body can help me with this?

**1. vsftpd config**

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=13000
pasv_max_port=13100
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=[public ip address of AWS EC2 instance]
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

**2. AWS EC2 Firewall**

[image: security groups (Inbound) setting]

**3. Test through FireFTP**

[image: Without IPV6 selected]

With `PASV` mode, I cannot connect to FTP server, the log is:

```
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
USER sensor
331 Please specify the password.
PASS (password not shown)
230 Login successful.
CWD /
250 Directory successfully changed.
TYPE A
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
PASV
QUIT
```

However, with it works with `EPSV` (with IPV6 checkbox selected), the log as below:

```
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
USER sensor
331 Please specify the password.
PASS (password not shown)
230 Login successful.
PWD
257 "/" is the current directory
TYPE A
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
EPSV
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||13082|)
LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
```

**4. Test through Python ftplib**

```python
from ftplib import FTP
contents = []
ftp = FTP(host=xxx, timeout=3000)
ftp.login(user=xxx, passwd=xxx)
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.retrlines("NLST", contents.append)
ftp.quit()
```

The log as below:

```
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Switching to ASCII mode.\n'
*resp* '200 Switching to ASCII mode.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,50,245).\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,50,245).'
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like a bug in vsftpd to me.

From the code it looks like, it will always send the `0,0,0,0`, if the public `pasv_address` is set, but the server has a (local) IPv6 address.

To fix this, make sure the server does not listen on IPv6 address (what is the default behavior, which you are overriding by setting `listen_ipv6=YES`):

```
listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES
```

The only other solution is removing a private IPv6 address, if it is possible in EC2.

Or use another FTP server, e.g. [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/).

Or make ftplib ignore the IP address returned by the server.
See [Cannot list FTP directory using ftplib – but FTP client works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55814722/850848)

---

To prove that this is indeed a bug, check this code of the latest vsftpd release (3.0.3):

`handle_pasv` in `postlogin.c`:

```c
int is_ipv6 = vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_is_ipv6(p_sess->p_local_addr);

...

if (tunable_pasv_address != 0)
{
  vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_alloc_ipv4(&s_p_sockaddr);
  /* Report passive address as specified in configuration */
  if (vsf_sysutil_inet_aton(tunable_pasv_address, s_p_sockaddr) == 0)
  {
    die("invalid pasv_address");
  }
}
else
{
  vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_clone(&s_p_sockaddr, p_sess->p_local_addr);
}
str_alloc_text(&s_pasv_res_str, "Entering Passive Mode (");
if (!is_ipv6)
{
  str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, vsf_sysutil_inet_ntop(s_p_sockaddr));
}
else
{
  const void* p_v4addr = vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4(s_p_sockaddr);
  if (p_v4addr)
  {
    str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, vsf_sysutil_inet_ntoa(p_v4addr));
  }
  else
  {
    str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, "0,0,0,0");
  }
}
```

where the `vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4` returns 0, if the `s_p_sockaddr` is not IPv6, what it never is, when the `pasv_address` is set.

`sysutil.c`:

```c
const void*
vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4(const struct vsf_sysutil_sockaddr* p_addr)
{
  static unsigned char pattern[12] =
      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF };
  const unsigned char* p_addr_start;
  if (p_addr->u.u_sockaddr.sa_family != AF_INET6)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (vsf_sysutil_memcmp(pattern, &p_addr->u.u_sockaddr_in6.sin6_addr, 12))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  p_addr_start = (const unsigned char*)&p_addr->u.u_sockaddr_in6.sin6_addr;
  return &p_addr_start[12];
}
```

Imho, the code is wrong. It works (and makes sense), when the IP address is "autodetected" from `p_sess->p_local_addr`, but fails, when the `pasv_address` address is used.

Consider reporting this to the author of vsftpd.

---

Keeping an original explanation of the `PASV` vs. `EPSV`:

Just to explain the difference between the `PASV` and the `EPSV`: The `PASV` returns an IP address in the response. That information is in 99.9% redundant. And it commonly causes problems, when the server is not aware of its external IP address.

The `EPSV` was introduced later than the `PASV`, when it was clear that the IP address presence in the response is problematic. So with the `EPSV`, only a port number is included. And the client connects to the FTP server IP address implicitly.

If the server really returns `0,0,0,0` in a response to the `PASV` command, it's clear why the client cannot connect to the server, when the `PASV` is used.

Comment: Great explanations, appreciated! Cannot do anything about the private IPv6 address of EC2, I have to change and try another FTP server now.