# I got "ConnectionRefusedError" when I try to list an FTP server

Tags: python, linux, ftp, debian, ftplib

I have a simple script to connect into a FTP server:

```
from ftplib import FTP

# Here is fine
ftp = FTP(host='')
ftp.login(user='', passwd='')
ftp.cwd('/test/')

# Here I got the error
ftp.nlst()
```

The connection it is just fine, the error is happening every time that I try to use commands to list the FTP directory, such as **nlst**, **dir** or even **retrlines('LIST')**:

```
230 Login successful.
250 Directory successfully changed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(a.nlst())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 558, in nlst
    self.retrlines(cmd, files.append)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 467, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 398, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 360, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 712, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 703, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I already tested the connection with FileZilla and it is working fine, this error just happens when I try to list the directory with python. If I try to retrieve files or create directories through python it will work, only the "list" commands that gives the problem.

**Environment**: I'm using debian 9 with python3.5

I already reinstalled both pythons (2 and 3) in my machine but didn't worked.
Also, I tested the same script in a Linux Mint that I have and it is working fine.
Could someone know what this could be? Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

This is the FileZilla log (debug mode) when I connect to the same FTP server:

```
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    USER xxxxxx
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    PASS ************
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   230 Login successful.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
Command:    SYST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 7
Command:    FEAT
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:   211 End
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Trace:  Measured latency of 40 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    TYPE I
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,195,59).
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Trace:    Reply: 0.0.0.0, peer: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Command:    LIST
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 3
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/test"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 4
Command:    CWD files
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   257 "/test" is the current directory
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,167,55).
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Trace:    Reply: 0.0.0.0, peer: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Command:    LIST
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnClose(0)
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 3
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Directory listing of "/test" successful
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

Just reminding that the code is working fine in another machines, the problem is happening only in Debian when I try to list any directory in the FTP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Command:    PASV  
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,195,59).  
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
```

Your FTP server is misconfigured. Or rather suffers from a vsftpd bug described in [vsftpd returns 0,0,0,0 in response to PASV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41046707/850848).

While FileZilla can heuristically workaround that, many other FTP clients and libraries will (rightfully) fail.

I cannot imagine how your code can work on *"other machines"*. Unless a firewall/NAT between their and the FTP server networks fix the `227` response (unlikely). *If you want to investigate that further (probably not worth it), we need log files of FTP sessions of your program (e.g. using Wireshark of server-side logs).*